# How to set copy option on discord bot button?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to give my discord bot feature to shorten URL. I want to give it a button option which will copy the shortened URL to users clipboard. How do I implement the feature using `ButtonBuilder`?

Comment: A copying function comes from the user's operating system, which a Discord bot cannot manipulate in that manner

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a user copy a string using a button. What you can do is redirect the user to a web page you built, that contains a copy button.

For example, your button will redirect users to `https://your-website.com?copy=https://google.com`. where `copy` value is the shortened URL.

your-website.com (that you will create) will take the `copy` url parameter and show a button to copy the it.